# how to create object of model when using in backbone js in javascript

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, javascript-objects

My problem is that i want to create object of model in javascript .I use backbone.js
I want to share model object globally because I need that object in many js files

```
 (function(){
     this.mymodel=Backbone.Model.extend({
            ----
            ----
     });
  return{
            var colobj = new mymodel;
  }
})
```

and I am sharing "colobj" object in another js file as follows

```
(function(){
     var collectionobj = new colobj;
 });
```

but this gives me error what is wrong in this example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should change this line :

```
var colobj = new mymodel;
```

to

```
var colobj = new this.mymodel;
```

The thing is that `mymodel` was undefined and that may have been the roots of your problem.

In addition, your first `colobj` is an instance of your model, thus it is an object and not a constructor. That's why the second time you try to instantiate it :

```
var collectionobj = new colobj;
```

it throws an error, because the browser thinks you're doing something like :

```
var collectionobj = new (new mymodel);
```

I suggest you pass only the model definition  the from one closure to another:

```
//...
return{
        var colobj = this.mymodel;
}
//...
```

**UPDATE**
I'm very surprised to see that I've missed this before.
You are returning an invalid object :

```
{var colobj = new mymodel;}
```

I think that you probably meant to return an object that hash a `colobj` property with the value of your model. If that's the case, all you have to do is return this object :

```
{colobj : this.mymodel};
```

Comment: still i get the following error :missing : after property id
var colobj = new this.mymodel; in this line

Comment: but when i am creating object of "colobj" in another js it gives me "colobj is not defined" error ..thanks ...

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me, you don't understand what is a closure, and how to use [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/).

You have a few options to do what you want.

At first, you could just use the global object to share objects across files. Like this:

```
// model.js
(function(exports, Backbone, undefined) {
    var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({});

    exports.Model = Model;
})(window, Backbone);

// collection.js
(function(exports, Backbone, _, undefined) {
    var Model = exports.Model;
    var Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Model
        // ...
    });

    exports.Collection = Collection;
})(window, Backbone, _);
```

Or this:

```
// model.js
Model = (function(Backbone, undefined) {
    var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({});

    return Model;
})(Backbone);

// collection.js
Collection = (function(Backbone, _, undefined) {
    var Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Model
        // ...
    });

    return Collection;
})(Backbone, _);
```

Or you could create an object in a global space and use it as a namespace.

```
// model.js
(function(App, Backbone, undefined) {
    var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({});

    App.Model = Model;
})(App = (window.App || {}), Backbone);

// collection.js
(function(App, Backbone, _, undefined) {
    var Model = App.Model;
    var Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Model
        // ...
    });

    App.Collection = Collection;
})(App = (window.App || {}), Backbone, _);
```

Or you could define your objects as [AMD-modules](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html) and then use any AMD loader. For example, if you would like to use require.js you could write something like this:

```
// main.js
require.config({
    paths: {
        'jquery': '/js/vendor/jquery.js',
        'underscore': '/js/vendor/underscore.js',
        'backbone': '/js/vendor/backbone.js',
        'model': '/js/model.js',
        'collection': '/js/collection.js'
    },
    shim: {
        backbone: {
            deps: ["underscore", "jquery"],
            exports: "Backbone"
        },

        underscore: {
            exports: "_"
        }
    }
});

// model.js
define([
    'jquery', 
    'underscore',
    'backbone'
], function($, _, Backbone){
    var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({});
    return Model;
});

// collection.js
define([
    'jquery', 
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'model'
], function($, _, Backbone, Model){
    var Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Model
    });
    return Collection;
});
```